# Htmlunit auto-login to google

Tags: htmlunit

I am using htmlunit to automate logging on to a server with google (the red "Sign in with Google button"). This redirects https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin, where I must write the email and password attributes every time. Compared to if I go to that url in my browser, I can choose which account I want to use, I don't have to type in my password.

Where is that data stored, and how can I emulate it in htmlunit?

Comment: Serialize the WebClient between invocations, or use `webClient.setCookieManager`

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about serialization.